# How to center a bigger background

Tags: html, css

I've done plenty of research on this but I must be doing something wrong because it never works for me. What I want to do is center the Vignette.png to overlay my other background, which is a repeating pattern. Unfortunately I can't still post images because of my still very low reputation :-). But basically what I want is the vignette, which is an image with 4k resolution, to center itself on the page, an if you have a bigger screen, you will see the surplus. But what seems to happen is that the image starts rendering at the top left corner and i can't even see the center of the image, because my screen isn't big enough. Again, I wish i could put some images to clarify my problem, but hopefully i've explained it well.

This is my code:

```css
/* CSS */

body {
  background-image: url("Vignette.png"), url("Pattern.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-position: center, auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <title>WIP</title>
  <meta charset="UFT-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

</html>
```

Thanks for answering!

Comment: you can post a link to your image using i.stack.imgur or postimg.org

Comment: or you can make a fiddle at http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `background-attachment: fixed` to your CSS, and provide one generic rule for the position:

```css
body {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"), url("http://lorempixel.com/40/40/");
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <title>WIP</title>
  <meta charset="UFT-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
  
<body></body>

</html>
```

In response to your comment:

The `background-attachment: fixed` property allows the image to maintain it's position on the page regardless of the other elements, rather than inheriting it's position and thus flowing with the page.

The 'generic rule' I referred to simple replaces your rule which was in fact invalid CSS with a valid rule, which specifies the position of the background image to be centred both horizontally and vertically (in that order): `background-position: center center`.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked, although I don't understand it very well. Why does the position need to have a generic rule?. And why does the background position need to be fixed?

Comment: You're welcome! I'll update the answer for you with an explanation

Comment: @JocaPinto did you change your mind as to which answer worked?

Comment: no, i clicked the wrong thing, hopefully it's fixed now :-)
Also, thanks for the answer, i got it now.

Comment: @JocaPinto Haha no worries, did my explanation help you?

Comment: @JocaPinto Not a problem!

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand yet what exactly you want to achieve. But chances are that you get it trying with `background-size: cover` or `background-size: contain`.

Here is an example of centered image that expands until its actual size is reached, and then the margins/background appear, so it never goes bigger than its resolution:

```
#page {
  background-image: url('some-image.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

I hope it helps

Comment: That wasn't exactly what i was after but I will use that tip in another project, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use background-size: cover; for this. I included an example, is this what you were trying to reach?

Here is some information about the backround-size attribute.
http://devdocs.io/css/background-size

```css
/* CSS */

body {
  background-image: url("http://www.handleidinghtml.nl/html/afbeeldingen/voorbeelden/usa3.gif"), url("Pattern.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <title>WIP</title>
  <meta charset="UFT-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to chanche the size, but thank you so much anyway :-)